# mermaid c4 diagram: bad component placement

Tags: architecture, software-design, diagram, mermaid

I am playing with mermaid to build C4 diagrams in GitHub.

I cannot find any good way to place elements correctly.

I have tried putting 2 elements with a relation between them (see [live editor](https://mermaid.live/edit#pako:eNptjz8LwkAMxb_KERwUOjg4FVxscXPxEBSypG1qC727cpeKRfrdPSr-GdzyyO-9vDygdBVDCtkmc1b4LmjR6jEIm2Vgf2tLThTCYVT6pRBWbyAvlhUJFRTeTL6b10fuvuZfZM9SNio4w6o1vfNCVmZgtp36OHI0axk7_pewcHUdWM5bhDXCR19eOkZAAoa9obaKPz3QqnhUGjaxdhrHimsaOkFAO0WUBnF6tCWk4gdOYJgL5C1dPRlIa-oCT08bLWOY)).

Both elements are located so close to each that relation text is not visible.

Is there any way to improve this?

I have also tried adding empty element with white background (see [live editor](https://mermaid.live/edit#pako:eNptkE1LxEAMhv_KEPZQocIieyp4sdWbF4ugkEvaSbeF-SgzqVqW_e-OU9RFhBySd948SeYEvdcMFdSH2jvhD0GHrl2jsC0ih7ep51IhPK6q3SqEK3S1t7N37KRgO8taIlDUW0TKjg3RdIUmoY7iN6W5y89PbH7xl5YHln5U0VtWU5oRhJxkQ257nlPKqbmV1fB_hJ0fhsjycotwfdgj_CivX8rN_gJzb9imEzbUdofadcfaGx-S-X2chDOg80Fz-KMnDJRgOViadPrAEzqV9pcxQRGqlGoeaDGCgO6crLSIb1fXQyVh4RKWvEQz0TGQhWogE_n8CSYXilo)).

However, then we depend on the background colour that is different across GitHub themes.

Anyway, empty element which requires it's own `UpdateElementStyle` block seems as workaround for me.

I hope there's a better native solution for this.